# sem_wait getting stuck while using -m32 option during compilation in 64-bit ubuntu linux

Tags: gcc, compilation, 32-bit

In 64-bit Ubuntu linux, while compiling & running the code with following command
[gcc -g -m64 sem_sample1.c -o sem_sample1 -lpthread], it works fine.

But while compiling with 32 bit option command
[gcc -g -m32 sem_sample1.c -o sem_sample1 -lpthread], execution gets stuck in sem_wait.

Is there a way to get around with -m32 option?

Snippet of sample code below:

```
void func1()
{
   sleep(2);
   sem_wait (SemOpenShmAddr[HSDPA_MT_PRINT_LOCK_SEM_IDX]);
   //do something
   sem_post (SemOpenShmAddr[HSDPA_MT_PRINT_LOCK_SEM_IDX]);
   }
   printf(" exit func1");
}

void func2()
{
   sleep(2);
   sem_wait (SemOpenShmAddr[HSDPA_MT_PRINT_LOCK_SEM_IDX]);
   //do something
   sem_post (SemOpenShmAddr[HSDPA_MT_PRINT_LOCK_SEM_IDX]);
   }
   printf(" exit func2");
}


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork ();

    if (HSDPA_MT_ZERO == pid)
    {
        //child1
        func1();
    }
    else
    {
        //parent
        func2();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't post a _Snippet of sample code_, but a compilable program.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  You might find this post helpful for providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).